# Insert grades only for student missing those grades with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, cross-join

I'm new to SQL and have this problem: I must check if every student has all grades (1-10). If a student is missing a grade, I must insert it. But no student should have duplicates of the same grade - they should have it exactly once.

All that I've done is to display all students with their grades:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(studentdata.FirstName,studentdata.LastName) AS 'Name', grade.Grade
 FROM studentdata
 CROSS JOIN grade
 WHERE studentdata.Id = grade.IdStudent
 ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: mysql or sql-swerver?

Comment: mysql. sorry i give wrong tag

Comment: `i must insert the missing grade`  How to determine this rating?

Comment: Well...first i must check every grade of the students and if a grade is missing, i must insert it. but i don't know how to do this...

Comment: What is the value of that rating?

Comment: 'i must don't get duplicates grades'  Do you mean that two different student can't have same grade?

Comment: 1,2,3..10. depends what's grade is missing

Comment: KDGamage 
no. every student must have all grades: 1-10. not duplicates, the student must not have a grade twice

Comment: This is an example for what i must do:
http://prntscr.com/92pf4e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have table `gradelevels` with only one column (`Grade`) with the possible grade values (1, 2, 3, ..., 10) you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO grade
SELECT
   studentdata.Id AS IdStudent,
   gradelevels.Grade AS Grade
FROM studentdata                  -- Get all the students,
CROSS JOIN gradelevels            -- one time for each possible grade.
LEFT JOIN grade ON
  -- Now we will know what (student, grade) combinations have an entry in grade.
  studentdata.Id = grade.IdStudent AND gradelevels.Grade = grade.Grade
WHERE grade.IdStudent IS NULL     -- Only take the rows where there isnt already a grade.
```

If you dont want to have a specific table with the gradelevels, you can just replace `CROSS JOIN gradelevels` with this:

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Grade FROM grade GROUP BY Grade) gradelevels
```

The `SELECT` will give you all of the grades that are used, so if there is some grade that is not used for any students, it will not be inserted.

I would recommend you to have an unique index on `IdStudent` and `Grade` in the table `Grade` (or have them as primary key), to ensure no student has the same grade twice.

Comment: my studentdata table: http://prntscr.com/92po9q
my grade table: http://prntscr.com/92pq7o
i haven't another table. and i can't create another table

Comment: I have updated my answer to adress that issue. Please do not post extra information in comments. Instead add it to the question by editing if you think it is needed. But please do not add links or pictures, if you want to add it, write it in text instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can view all student with or without grades with this Query:

```
Select CONCAT(sd.FirstName,sd.LastName) AS 'Name', grade.Grade
from studentdata sd 
left outer join grade 
on sd.Id = grade.IdStudent
```

if you must only see students without grade:

```
Select CONCAT(sd.FirstName,sd.LastName) AS 'Name', grade.Grade
from studentdata sd 
left outer join grade 
on sd.Id = grade.IdStudent
WHERE ISNULL(grade.Grade, -1000) = -1000
```

Finally to insert a default grade of "5":

```
insert into grade (id, grade)
Select CONCAT(sd.FirstName,sd.LastName) AS 'Name', isnull(grade.Grade, 5) as Grade
from studentdata sd 
left outer join grade 
on sd.Id = grade.IdStudent
WHERE ISNULL(grade.Grade, -1000) = -1000
```

since your grade table seems to hold all grades for all assignments, you want to add to the where statement, a "andgrade.assigmentid =

Comment: Why `ISNULL(grade.Grade, -1000) = -1000` and not `grade.Grade IS NULL`? Also, I think every student should have *all* grades (1-10) and not just a default grade of 5. But not sure since the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: yes. every student must have all grades.
like here: http://prntscr.com/92pf4e
this is what i must have in the end

Comment: I would recommend you to add that information to your question (but not as a picture) instead of just posting it in comments.